# How to merge two options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two different options in JavaScript

Option 1:

```
        var _option = {
            "displayLength": _length,
            "order": [[ _order, ""+_sort+"" ]],
            "paging": _pages,
            "info": _info,
            "searching": _search
        }
```

Option 2:

```
        var _button_option = {
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy',
                'excel',
                'print'
            ]
        }
```

I want to merge two option values to the one values

Result like this:

```
        var _option = {
            "displayLength": _length,
            "order": [[ _order, ""+_sort+"" ]],
            "paging": _pages,
            "info": _info,
            "searching": _search,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy',
                'excel',
                'print'
            ]
        }
```

How to merge two options in JavaScript?

Comment: You can use spread syntax to combine two javascripts objects.
var combined = {..._option, ..._button_option};
Read more about spread syntax on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Object.assign [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
_option =  Object.assign({}, _option, _button_option)
```

or

```
Object.assign(_option, _button_option)
```

Or you can spread it like

```
_option = {..._option, ..._button_option}
```

For reference visit [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: For anyone wondering why [tag:jquery] has a `$.extend` when this exists, please refer to: https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_object_assign